# Send email with line breaks using mail() in php

Tags: php

I am trying to send email using mail() in php. I need the message to be formatted or at least allow line breaks.

```
$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
 "From: ".$name." <".$email.">/r/n"
 ."Reply-To: ".$email."/r/n"    
 ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

Do i need to provide "< br/>" tags in the $message or /r/n. Tried both but they came in as 
 or /r/n and not line breaks

Thanks
Prady

Comment: note: anyone you expose those variables to (ie, from a website or database) can preform an injection attack. See example here: http://www.hackpconline.com/2010/10/what-is-crlf-injection-crlf-injections.html

Comment: try this "\r\n" , instead of  this "/r/n"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's \r\n, as in backslash not forward slash.

Also you can try it like this:

```
$message = "

Hi!

This is one line.

And this is another.



Bye!
";
```

Comment: Strangely `\r\n` wouldn't work for me, this did though.

Comment: Please Please note that the control characters \ r \ n do not work with single quotes. When using \r\n control characters always use double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

you should set the content type of the mail
(read: tell php you're sending a html e-mail)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

it's all explained in Example #5 Sending HTML email.

Answer (score 1):

because it's \r\n

Comment: about <br/> it would make sense only if the mail is sent as HTML otherwise it will only print those 5 characters

Answer (score 1):

It's the solution I got after waisting too many time and It's working perfectly.

```
echo "line 1".PHP_EOL."line 2".PHP_EOL;
```

If you're planning to show the result in a browser then you have to use `"<br>"`.

Answer (score 0):

To format message body you should use \n, as follow:

```
$message = "Hi!
\nThis is one line.
\nAnd this is another.
\nBye!";
```

This is formatting your message body.