# How do I add line break in PHP in e-mail forms?

Tags: php, email

I know that this question has been asked numerous times, but I am unable to add the 
 or \n tag to the right place in the code below:
I would like to list the name of the sender, the phone number etc... in different lines in the e-mail. Would you be able to point out the "exact" location I need to add the code please?

```
// Read the form values
$success = false;
$senderName = isset( $_POST['username'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['username'] ) : "";

$recommenderEmail = isset($_POST['recommender-email']) ? preg_replace("/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['recommender-email']) : "";

$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['email'] ) : "";

$phone = isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['phone'] ) : "";

$message = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['message'] ) : "";

$date = isset( $_POST['date'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['date'] ) : "";

$timeToCall = isset( $_POST['time-to-call'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['time-to-call'] ) : "";

$referralAddress = isset( $_POST['referral-address'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['referral-address'] ) : "";

// If all "required" values exist, send the email
if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $phone && $recommenderEmail && $referralAddress) {
  $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
  $headers = "From: <" . $recommenderEmail . ">";

  $msgBody = " Referral Name: " . $senderName .  " Phone: " . $phone .  " E-Mail: " . $senderEmail . " Referral Address: " . $referralAddress .  " Move Date: " . $date .  " Best Time to Contact: " .  $timeToCall . " Message: " . $message . "";
  $success = mail( $recipient, $headers, $msgBody );
```

Thank you.

Comment: Show us what have you tried to solve the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email with line breaks using mail() in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786564/send-email-with-line-breaks-using-mail-in-php)

Comment: What a mess.. i advise you to use PHPMailer Class.

Comment: I have tried to insert <br> and \n into various sections of the code, but dreamweaver displays a syntax error and the php form becomes disfuntional.

Comment: Haha. I tried to create my own form from an online template. I am not programmer just a tinkerer. Hence the mess :)

Comment: instead of using \n try to display the result in a tabular form

Comment: My question is really simple yet nobody seem to be able to answer it. The first part is "what" function I use? The second is "where" do I use it in the code? Keshav suggested using "nl2br" so where do I insert it in the code?

Comment: Email looks like text/plain so it should just be: `$msgBody = "Referral Name: {$senderName}\nPhone: {$phone}\n ... and so on ...`

Comment: Yes. Cheers for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try \n in string for line change.

if it's not working create html template for email and add content type in email header 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'.

```
<?php
   //Read the form values 
    $success = false;
    $senderName = isset($_POST['username']) ? preg_replace("/[^.-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['username']) : "";
    $recommenderEmail = isset($_POST['recommender-email']) ? preg_replace("/[^.-_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['recommender-email']) : "";
    $senderEmail = isset($_POST['email']) ? preg_replace("/[^.-_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['email']) : "";
    $phone = isset($_POST['phone']) ? preg_replace("/[^.-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['phone']) : "";
    $message = isset($_POST['message']) ? preg_replace("/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['message']) : "";
    $date = isset($_POST['date']) ? preg_replace("/[^.-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['date']) : "";
    $timeToCall = isset($_POST['time-to-call']) ? preg_replace("/[^.-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['time-to-call']) : "";
    $referralAddress = isset($_POST['referral-address']) ? preg_replace("/[^.-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['referral-address']) : "";

    // If all "required" values exist, send the email if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $phone && $recommenderEmail && $referralAddress) { $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">"; $headers = "From: <" . $recommenderEmail . ">";

    $msgBody = " Referral Name: " . $senderName . "\n Phone: " . $phone . "\n E-Mail: " . $senderEmail . "\n Referral Address: " . $referralAddress . "\n Move Date: " . $date . "\n Best Time to Contact: " . $timeToCall . "\n Message: " . $message . "";
    $success = mail($recipient, $headers, $msgBody);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can use`nl2br` function for that
here is the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Thanks, but can I not use the "\n" for the sake of simplicity? And if I can then where do I add it to my code?